# Can I set a custom dimention within setAction in ec.js (Google Analytics)?

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I've been searching Google but really there is no answer. Perhaps any of you guys here know: would the code below work:

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', { // Transaction details are provided in an actionFieldObject.

'id': 'T12345', // (Required) Transaction id (string).

'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online', // Affiliation (string).

'revenue': '37.39', // Revenue (currency).

'tax': '2.85', // Tax (currency).

'shipping': '5.34', // Shipping (currency).

'coupon': 'SUMMER2013', // Transaction coupon (string).

'dimension1': 'custom1',

'dimension2': 'custom2'

});
```

I mean if custom dimension can be set here within the setAction or not?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Custom dimensions are set either in hit scope (referring to individual actions), product scope (with Enhanced E-Commcerce, so to speak a special case of hit scope), session scope (i.e. referring to all pageview within a visit) or user scope (referring to all sessions of a recurring user).

There is no "setAction"-scope or anything like it. I haven't tested the code and it might even work by accident, but even so it would still end up in hit/session/user scope, depending on the backend settings for your dimensions and thus would be pointless.

Comment: Yes, this sounds very reasonable - it would probably be a hit scope dimension, so I can set it ouside setAction as it would be more reliable with the same effect. Thank you!